# Scraping Facebook Shares - Pagination Returning Empty List

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a list of people who have shared a Facebook Post.  I know I'll only be able to get a subset due to privacy settings, but I'm still failing to get the shares that are publicly visible.

If I go to:
     https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/sharedposts?access_token=accesstoken, I can see maybe two shares, despite the fact that I can see 11 on the page.  I can see the 'next'page:

```
"paging": {

  "cursors": {

     "before": "MTAxNTU3Njc4NTM4MjA2NDk6OTow",

     "after": "MTczMjU0NDQ1MzQ0MTE0MDo5OjAZD"

  },

"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/post_id/sharedposts?access_token=accesstoken&pretty=1&limit=25&after=MTczMjU0NDQ1MzQ0MTE0MDo5OjAZD"
   }
}
```

But if I try to open the "next" url it just gives me an empty list.

I've looked and seen similar problems but no solution that I've been able to understand/get to work.

Has anyone been able to solve this?  Or to find a way to scrape the publicly visible shares of a post?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Even if the shares are public, you would need user_posts permission from the user that shared.

Comment: Sorry if this is really obvious, but do you know how I might go about getting that?

Comment: @CBroe Ignore me, I can't do it for this group of users - thanks anyway!

Comment: The users would have to log in to your app to grand it that permission. Since you don’t know which users will share the post, you would not know which ones to ask to do that in the first place.